# Why are the limits of the integration this way round?

Tags: integration, limits

The question I'm doing is:

$$ \iint_{R}xy^2 \,dA$$ where $R$ is the finite region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$.

I get how they have split the integral up but I don't get why the limits of the $dy$ integral are in the order that they are. I would have put $x^2$ at the top because it is bigger but I know this is not the rule.

$$\int_0^1 x \, dx \int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} y^2 \, dy$$

Thanks

Comment: "I would have put $x^2$ at the top because it is bigger but I know this is not the rule."

It isn't bigger. Compare them at $x = 1/4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Take a look atat the following sketch of the domain of integration:

[image]

Comment: So it's because the x=y^2 is on the top of the region?

Comment: Yess!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

When $0 < x < 1$, we have $\sqrt{x} > x^2$, hence the lower limit is $x^2$ and the upper limit is $\sqrt{x}$.

It is also worth noting that the integral cannot be written as $$\int_{x=0}^1 x \, dx \int_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} y^2 \, dy.$$  This is wrong:  The correct expression is $$\int_{x=0}^1 \left(x \int_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} y^2 \, dy \right) dx.$$  This is because the inner integral with respect to $y$ becomes a function of $x$ when evaluated at the limits.  Then the resulting function of $x$ is integrated on $x \in [0,1]$.